# jahmm-how to generate output states for a given sequence using a trained HMM

Tags: java, hidden-markov-models

I used Jahmm to train an HMM using my input sequence. After the training is complete, I have learnt HMM model and my initial input sequence. How do I generate the output states for the input sequence using the learnt HMM model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for the most likely state sequence for a given input sequence.
This can be retrieved using `ViterbiCalculator.stateSequence()` in the jahmm package, see the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Jahmm user guide from [here](http://www.run.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~francois/software/jahmm/doc/userguide/0.6.1/jahmm-userguide-0.6.1.pdf). You can go through this doc for more details about the working of *Jahmm*.